# Exporting to .eps using QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, resolution, file-formats

According to web posts from a few years ago, exporting to .eps was easy with QGIS.  Just choose : Export as image --> select .eps type.  However, I do not find that functionality in the current version of QGIS.

Has it been removed as an option or is there another route to get there?

Context: I am preparing my figures for submission to a journal for publication.  The journal requires over 300dpi (high resolution) .tiff or .eps format.  When I export my map from QGIS in over 300dpi as a .tiff, the file size is too big for the journal's webserver to upload.  As an alternative, I am hoping to export as .eps to conserve file resolution but keep file size down as I have with my graphs exports from R.

Comment: the option is now `save as image` EPS is one of the formats I see then

Comment: @iant - I do not see this option for QGIS 2.16.1-Nødebo, Win7 64-bit. Perhaps a platform issue?

Comment: I'm ubuntu 14.0.4

Comment: for Windows export to SVG and convert is using https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-eps

Comment: Similarly, I do not have the option to save as image (only "export as image") with QGIS 2.8.1.  Also, the export SVG doesn't work correctly (e.g. map shifts into the legend space) and converting to .eps with cloudconvert is even worse. [QGIS seems aware that SVG doesn't work since it displays an error message before saving]

Comment: I have not had any issue exporting to svg and making print ready in illustrator. you might have to try a higher version of qgis (you can have many QGIS versions on your windows machine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature seems to be platform-dependent.

On Windows standalone and OSGEO4W (QGIS 2.16 and qgis-dev 64-bit), available formats are `BMP,ICO,JPG,PNG,PPM,TIF,XBM and XPM`.

Ubuntu and similar (debian and ubuntugis repo) have additionally `BW,EPS,EPSF,EPSI,JP2,PCX,PIC,RGB,RGBA,SGI,TGA,WEBP and XV`.

This seems to be introduced some time after QGIS 2.8.1.

You can install Ubuntu or Linux Mint in a virtual box to get the feature on a Windows machine too. Using shared folders, you can even access .qgis project files inside the guest system.

The print composer has additional exports to SVG and PDF as separate menu entries, but a warning regarding SVG export.

Keep an eye on http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15443 for progress on the matter.

Comment: As stated by @AndreJ, works for Ubuntu (but even not for Lubuntu). However, I am getting a mixture of many raster overlays in the output, which is not what I would expected. Whenever I need a vector in the output, PDF (disable/deny *Print as raster*) works good for me (QGIS v2.18).

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu Bionic, QGIS 3.2 (and higher) Bonn, does not have EPS support.
Only: BMP, CUR, ICO, JPEG, JPG, PBM, PGM, PNG, PM, XBM and XPM are supported under "Export To Image".

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this option in Windows or Linux Mint using QGIS 2.14

However, depending on how many images you're looking to export, we have gotten around a few shortcomings of export options using Inkscape - Exporting images to PDF then opening in Inkscape and saving as SVG in order to preserve text (rather than paths) for use in Illustrator (our graphics department), for example.

Again, depending on your workflow and number of files, you might try this out.

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows 11 export in QGIS to Tiff format at the resolution the journal wants, and then convert the image to EPS format using GIMP image editing software.

Other way it's quite complicated. My master thesis project was done for example in an older version of QGIS (2.18), so the program couldn't open my project on a newer version of QGIS (3.xx). This made me waste several hours, until I found out what the culprit was. This is also an important detail to note.

It's horrible having to rework your layers and go in depth again when all you need is just to submit the image in a different format. So, just use GIMP.

Anyways, hope it helps someone.